# Assign a value if RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
post = Post.find 666

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Post with 'id'=666
```

post => nil

```
post = "Banana"
post = Post.find 666
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Post with 'id'=666
```

post => "Banana"

I want to make sure `post` is `nil` if the find doesn't return anything.  Is there an elegant way of assigning nil if it comes up empty handed?

Comment: How can a post be a "Banana"?

Comment: I set post = "Banana" on line #1 of the second code block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how to do it:

```
post = Post.find_by(id: 666)
```

Comment: Yeah, this returns the first post if the params are nil.

Comment: "I want to make sure post is nil if the find doesn't return anything." That's exactly what this does. If there is no post with id 666, post is nil.

Comment: @Ashbury - Not sure what params has to do with the question. If you are doing `find_by(id: params[ :id ])`, and there is no :id param, then post will be nil.

Comment: Oh you are correct, I didn't specify :id like a regular find method!

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using `find`, you need to `rescue` the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception. However, this is very slow, and hardly Rails idiomatic, so I suggest you use `find_by` as suggested in the answer above.

```
begin
  post = Post.find(666)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  post = "Banana"
end
```